# how to find minimum form piecewise function

Tags: calculus

Equation:
$$(1+6.64x)^2+4(1+8.89x)^2-8(1+6.64x)-16(1+8.89x)-(\frac{1}{((1+6.64x)+(1+8.89x)-5)}+\frac{1}{((1+6.64x)-3)}-\frac{1}{(1+6.64x)}-\frac{1}{(1+8.89x)})$$

plot and solution form wolframalpha [Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bx*6.64)%5E2%2B4(1%2Bx*8.89)%5E2-8(1%2Bx*6.64)-16(1%2Bx*8.89)-(1%2F((1%2Bx*6.64)%2B(1%2Bx*8.89)-5)%2B1%2F((1%2Bx*6.64)-3)-1%2F((1%2Bx*6.64))-1%2F((1%2Bx*8.89))))
U can see 5 pieces of function only one have minimum

I find some example from youtube but most of them give u domain for each pieces but this example give u nothing
anyway to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

the general strategy is as follows:

when you have a piecewise function, at the first step the domain of the function should be calculated, for doing that calculate the domain of each piece and then take the intersection of all domains, this will give you the final domain which is indeed the domain of the function, then if the domain of your function is open interval such $(a,b)$, half-closed interval such $\left[a,b\right)$ or $\left(a,b\right]$ then calculate limit function as $x$ approaches to the open interval, sometimes the limit gives you $+∞$ or $-∞$ (assuming $x$ belong to the domain), in this cases respectively the function does not have any  global maximum ,global minimum.

then take the derivative of each piece and compute the root(s) of each derivative, after that you should determine the value of the function for the root(s) of the derivatives, comparing the values (considering the above limits which I mentioned) will give you the final answer whether the function does have any global extrema or not.(the function you've mentined is not actually a piecewise function, because it has not been defined by multiple sub-functions, therefore for every $x∈D_f$ the function is the same.  )

and about your example first of all simplify the function:

$\small f(x)=1+2\left(6.64x\right)+\left(6.64\right)^2x^2+4+8\left(8.89x\right)+\left(8.89\right)^2x^2-8-8\left(6.64x\right)-16-16\left(8.89x\right)$
$\normalsize-\left(\frac{1}{((1+6.64x)+(1+8.89x)-5)}+\frac{1}{((1+6.64x)-3)}-\frac{1}{(1+6.64x)}-\frac{1}{(1+8.89x)}\right)$

the growth rate of the function depends on $x^2$, in other words the function $f(x)$ can be written such that :$f(x)=\mathcal{O}(x^2)$, the domain of the function is $\left(-∞,+∞\right)-\left\{x∉D_f\right\}$,as I mentioned above if the domain of the function is in the form $(a,b)$ so limit function as $x$ approaches to $\pm ∞$ should be computed, hence $\large\lim_{x\rightarrow \pm ∞}f(x)=+∞$, implies the function does not have any global extrema .